# I want to make the content of the boy Scrolling in flutter

Tags: flutter

when i trie to wrap the Center widget of the body into a SingleChildScrollView i am getting this issue and  i don't see the content of the page anymore

```
 ══════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderPositionedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    Center
```

if some one can help i would appreciate
and there is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class DetailLivre extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailLivreState createState() => _DetailLivreState();
}

class _DetailLivreState extends State<DetailLivre> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _backgroundColor = Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    final _tailleWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final _couleurIcons = Colors.blueGrey[200];
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: _couleurIcons,
          ),
          onPressed: () =>
              Navigator.pop(context), // Me redirige à la page précédante
        ),
        title: Text(
          'My Books',
          style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFB0BEC5)),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                  top: _tailleWidth.height / 35,
                  right: _tailleWidth.width / 2.9,
                  child: Container(
                      height: _tailleWidth.height / 5.0,
                      width: _tailleWidth.width / 4.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: AssetImage('images/4.jpg'))))),


            ]
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(color: Colors.black26, spreadRadius: 0, blurRadius: 7.0),
          ],
        ),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          color: _backgroundColor,
          elevation: 10.0,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        elevation: 6.0,
        onPressed: () => setState(() {}),
        child: Icon(
          Icons.play_arrow,
          size: 40.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

but it didn't work it show a white screen  when the SignleChildScrollView is wrapped with the Center widget of the Body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Positioned Widget in Stack, the Stack widget must have some space. In your case, the stack is empty, nor it is inside a parent container. So Positioned Widget is not working. And you are getting wrong error message. SingleChildScrollView is not the reason behind error.

To define space for the stack u can do 2 things.

1. Wrap the Stack Widget inside a Container widget and give it some height width.
2. Or Insert a Container Inside a Stack

Container(
  height: 200,
  Width: 200,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
    Positioned(...)
    ]
  )
)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it seemed to be my issue, i see know.